# Limpar seleção de subfiltro

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma opção no meu site que é a facilidade de pesquisar os produtos pelos subfiltros, mas agora tenho um problema, preciso "limpar" essa navegação, voltando ao antes de pesquisa, usei uma técnica nada interessante na tentativa de resolver o problema, crie um botão e coloquei nele o seguinte código:

```
<a class="button orange"href="javascript:window.history.go(-1)">Limpar Filtros</a>
```

Mas claro, tenho alguns problemas com isso, se o cliente navegar por mais de um filtro ele retornará exatamente por onde ele passou.
Não consegui ter uma solução para isso, se preferirem ver o exemplo, acessem aqui e naveguem pelos subfiltros e cliquem no botão "limpar filtros":

[Site em desenvolvimento](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2&sub=14)

Comment: O comando javascript:window.history.go(-1) faz o mesmo de um click no "Back Page" no navegador. Com a sua estrutura atual, a maneira mais rápida de limpar os filtros é realizando um redirecionamento para a categoria inicial. Porém a solução ideal, seria os seus produtos carregados através de AJAX mantendo os seus filtros intocados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você não tenha acesso ao código PHP. Caso tenha, o ideal seja que você link o botão de limpar filtros para: http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/produtos.php?dep=2&sub=14

Caso apenas seja possível alterar o código Javascript, vai uma solução:

```js
window.goBackToOriginalQuery = function () {
  var query = window.location.search.replace('?','').split('&');
  var depParam = '', subParam = '';
  for (var i = 0, j = query.length-1; i<j; i++) {
     var currentParam = query[i];
     if (currentParam.indexOf('dep') !== -1){
       depParam = currentParam;
     } else if (currentParam.indexOf('sub') !== -1) {
       subParam = currentParam;
     }
  }

  var originalURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/msb/produtos.php?' + depParam + '&' + subParam;

  window.location.replace(originalURL);  
}
```

E no HTML:

```html
<a class="button orange"href="javascript:window.goBackToOriginalQuery()">Limpar Filtros</a>
```

Comment: Olá @Breno Calazans, suas dicas foram muito legais, mas a primeira é que se encaixou melhor, obrigado.